# No focus on shutdown buttons

Tags: shutdown

When I select "Switch Off..." from the drop down that appears when clicking on the power icon in the top right corner, the "Are you sure you want to shut down?" interface comes up. It has three buttons, `Restart`, `Cancel`, and `Shut Down`.

The `Shut Down` button is highlighted in red, but it doesn't have any focus. By which I mean that if I press the Enter key when these options are on screen, nothing happens. I necessarily have to use the mouse to click on the `Shut Down` button in order to shut down.

I'd like to just be able to access these three buttons by pressing tab to move between them, and enter to press them. Is that possible?

Comment: nice question. haven't recognized it till now

Answer (score 1):

This is a feature in Loki (the 2016 release). For example, "Restart" is highlighted below as I tab between the Shut Down menu options: [image: Shutdown dialog box]